# What to do with threats of blacklisting?

Tags: phd, ethics, united-kingdom

To be brief, I am a PhD student in the UK, and I have recently had some disagreement with the way my advisor handled our collaboration on research. This was initially a fairly minor thing. Not in the sense of what has happened, but minor in the sense that I only wanted to move past it, and to continue productively, but unfortunately he appeared to be too preoccupied, or for whatever reason, unable or unwilling to work together on correcting our results. Frustrating and not good for me, but ok, fine. At the time, no harsh words were exchanged at all, and there was some degree of understanding, although I was not happy with the mistake.

This has escalated beyond belief as soon as I relayed this problem to an administrative person, to explain there was a mutual mistake and I needed more time to submit. I explained the situation briefly to the person responsible for these things, made it clear I held no animosity or any interest in dwelling on it, and just needed some recovery time to move forwards. This was made totally clear to him and he was fine to shift the submission date and funding termination back slightly and he had agreed with me that there should be no blame here.

This has resulted in my advisor going on a furious rant at me in public, saying he refuses to work with me anymore. In private, the advisors have said that my 'complaints' have made the group look bad (no complaint was ever made, only a request for further time), and that they have now lodged some files or something on me with people at the university marking me as problematic. I have also been told that my complaints will make it difficult for me to get a job even after graduation, if I get to that point, because my advisor has no intention of giving me a reference, much less a positive one, and that they can make finding a job very difficult.

What on earth can I do? It seems that my career is now in ruins before it even started.

This whole situation has made me disgusted since it appears to have come almost out of nowhere, based on one conversation with an admin person. But I cannot work elsewhere if they follow through on their threats. How can I salvage my potential career?

Edit: There are just too many details I left out to edit down to size, and I would like to simply close this question or delete it if possible, due to confusion. I would prefer this to editing a popular question with too many specifics.

Comment: (1) please edit this down to the question you want us to ask. (2) Is this in the Anglosphere + Western Europe or somewhere else? That matters greatly as to how things work for this.

Comment: "I have also been told that my complaints etc." - told by whom?

Comment: Apologies for too much information. I have removed some things. My advisors have told me that due to my mentioning of these problems that they can make me unappealing to other staff/academics due to making them look bad.

Comment: You haven't yet provided an important piece of information: in which country is this happening? The answer can vary a lot from one country to another.

Comment: This is a UK system.

Comment: Did you consult with your advisor on whether to ask for extra time, and if so how it should be done?

Comment: What was a fairly minor thing? What did the advisor say has upset him? Also, careful about talking about "shared blame" (see below comments). This is a codeword for "actually it's you, but I want to be so generous to take part of it.", similar to the infamous *politician's apology*, "if I have offended somebody", which is not really one. Maybe indeed it is your adviser, but for you to be helped, please let us understand the complete picture. BTW, once realising one's mistake, heartfelt and unconditional apologies may work wonders, although it might be too late now in the present case.

Comment: I did request extra time from the advisor, considering the project had to be cancelled, but did not receive advice, unfortunately. @CaptainEmacs I did not say 'shared blame' in reality; I said why we were changing topic so close to an important date and mentioned that I must take blame myself for also not noticing the paper in my own reading. Again, maybe I removed too much information after being asked to edit things down, so sorry if this question is no good, maybe it should be removed.

Comment: I am not sure I fully grasp the situation. In the very beginning of your PhD, you were asked to verify the results you will be building on, which is a completely legitimate task. In some area (Computer Science, for example), it is almost necessary to have a working model of competing techniques to be able to compare fairly on your data. But then you say "_I was not happy with the mistake_". Following that, from what I understand, you went over your advisor head, and talked to the administrative person saying (basically) that he has been advising you wrongly and you need to recover from that.

Comment: Sorry for being blunt, but I am currently in the UK system, and while I absolutely do not condone _a furious rant in public_, if I was supervising a student who acted like that, I would be very offended. And while I might be able to admit that part of it comes from mistakes in advising and leading the student (and that, as a consequence, I might need to work on those skills as an advisor), I would take such a behaviour of the student as a big breach of trust, possibly big enough that I could not work with, advise or lead such a student any more.

Comment: @penelope Apologies, it appears I have made this question confusing but cannot close it since the first answer came so soon. It was not verification of results but that the problem had been already solved by a prior PhD student and was mistakenly brought up again, this was the problem. I tried to request more work but was told thanks but no, and after a month or so of this I was advised that I must say something to deal with this, but did not make any form of complaint.

Comment: Yes, it seems like you have indeed made the question confusing, as I am still not following your clarification. Not results verification, sure. But, you then say "work on a problem that has been solved", and besides the mathematical _prove property X", I don't see many problems in science "truly solved". Somebody proposes a good approach for problem X, and a year or two later, somebody working on the _same problem_ proposes a different approach. But, you said you were told "thanks no" when asking for more work, and then advised to say something to deal - who told you and advised you that?

Comment: Who is "the person responsible for these things" (in your edit)? Your advisor, the admin person, or did you involve yet a _third_ person in all of this? How is your advisor _not_ the person responsible for your project and work?

Comment: This is in mathematics, yes. The result in question had been proved by the previous PhD student in his thesis. He apologised to me but then seemed to just withdraw and avoid advising me for a month or so. The admin person was responsible for my funding, and they contacted me about my intent to submit as this relates to funding, and they probably noticed some delay since I know the guy casually as well.

Comment: I have a friend who is a professor in a UK university and he always rants (privately to me) how sensitive the environment is about complaints of any kind. Next time think twice before bringing stuff up to anyone. If you want a friendly and quick resolution go the private route. The moment you bring anything to any kind of authority, apparently, it's a huge issue in the UK independently of how small the initial fact is. And other answers below seem to corroborate all the examples I've heard from this friend of mine.

Comment: Luckily, the kind of person ranting about how they'll destroy your career and how many contacts they have etc. in almost all cases is just vastly overestimating their impact.

Comment: You can always threaten to run away. Learn some Russian just in case? :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You went to the administrative person. That was your error and the core issue.

Allow me to give an example from the other side in which this happened:

While I was at another institute, I was asked to take over a lab for another person. The lab hosted a guest cohort from another country so the university needed someone with content knowledge and dual language fluency on short notice. So I was asked if I could take over the lab for a week.

Suffice to say, I did not know that there were particular rules for this lab. Some were obvious (like not leaving equipment plugged in) but I was a little overwhelmed with taking over a course last minute. Further, my work is primarily computational rather than lab focused so the reflex nature of lab rules was not there for me.

After a few nights, the lab manager came in and saw the lab after I had left it. Equipment was left out and plugged in. All a very big mistake on my part. The way she responded was where things got messy.

In hindsight, a more measured response would have been talking to me or even the lab's PI to find out what was going; even going to the department head. Instead she went to the Dean. She did not know the situation with the lab and the dean didnt, but as soon as it went to the dean, the situation became "administrative". Funds were threatened and it ended with me having to write a formal apology to the department head and the lab manager with everyone CCed on the email.  Everyone was aware the situation and most parties were mainly pleased that I was willing to write the apology so the "administrative" side of the situation could go away and we could fix things in house. (I ended up just getting an assistant who was a little more lab savvy). The department head came by and gave me a sympathetic pat on the back.

Was I wrong, certainly. But it was likely an issue that could have been dealt with "in house".

So, what was the end result of going to the administration rather than keeping things in house?  At one end, awkward elevator rides when the lab manager and I crossed paths. She found out the situation, and to find out, she didnt even know I was in the lab. I heard she thought it was an undergraduate group. On the other end, it did leave some lasting trust issues and undermined what had been before a very good working relationship between two labs. But I think that things have smoothed out since that happened.

In other words, once you go to the administration, the situation becomes administrative.

Comment: Would you mind expanding on 'You went to the administrative person. That was your error and the core issue.'? I am not asking in a confrontational way - just genuinely a bit lost. I also cannot figure out the 'scale' of OP's situation, but let's assume that the situation was as OP describes it ('a fairly minor thing') and simply needed more time. If the administrator approves, OP did nothing wrong by being granted more time from higher authorities? Would love for some others to chime in!

Answer (score 13):

You have not quite told us what happened with you, your advisor and your research group. But even your vague description betrays what I believe to be a lack of awareness to certain aspects of professional/interpersonal interaction which is now biting you in the ass.

> This was initially a fairly minor thing. I just needed to explain to others that there was some confusion which my advisor admitted to me privately

This was not a minor, thing - it was a major thing. A *huge* thing probably. Why?

- You repeated something told to you in confidence, to outsiders, and made it (somewhat) generally known.
- You assigned blame to your advisor while (seemingly) hinting he was incapable/unwilling to take on the blame, thus slighting his character as a person and as a manager.

... and this was even *before* any official complaints were lodged about anything and anyone.

Now, maybe that's not the only way to look at what happened, but it could very well be the way that your advisor and many others - in and out of your research group - see things. It's possible that, on the merit of the original matter, what you said was true - but that doesn't help with how you conducted yourself.

> This whole situation has made me disgusted.

You must realize that the feeling may be mutual. Try to look at things from the other person's perspective - what do they expect and believe - and be aware that they will judge you *from that perspective*, not on the basis of the facts, or what you consider to be the facts and circumstances.

> What on earth can I do?

Unless it jeopardizes the integrity of yours and others research - swallow your pride/disgust, stash your ego somewhat, and apologize to your advisor for your conduct. Be, or pretend to be, penitent.

Does this mean that he's not really to blame for anything? Not really. Maybe most of the blame is with him. But - that doesn't really matter. You have to be generous with taking blame and cutting people slack (whether they deserve it in your opinion or not), as long as others/society/science don't suffer as a consequence. That's an important salve to apply to situations of people being offended.

Comment: Thank you for your advice, but I should make it clear I did not blame him, in fact I made it very clear I was not complaining about anything, only requesting more time due to a shared mistake. I took every step to say that the relationship was good. There was in fact no complaint lodged by me at all. I was requested to edit things down so I removed some clarifying information, perhaps. But there was no complaint ever lodged, informally or formally.

Comment: @user41208: This may be clear to you, but reading your question - the opposite was clear to me. I mean, you don't have to say "I'm blaming him" for another party to construe what you've said as an assignment of blaim to him.

Comment: Thanks for your perspective. I'm just wondering how this is interpreted as a complaint when the advisor is aware of me not actually making any complaint at all, only a request for further time, and how that escalates so rapidly to "I can make it very hard for you to find work." As for my comment about disgust, this related to further information I edited out after being asked to cut it down. The question is possibly a bit of a mess, I now realise.

Comment: @user41208, there is something missing in your story, if I understood, you only asked for extra time due to a shared mistake, I would like to know how you delivered this request to make this situation escalated to that point. The best thing you can do is to go and speak with a good professor who can smoothen the waters with your supervisor, maybe there is misunderstanding or gossiping.

Comment: It seems from your story, that your relationship with your supervisor was good, but I do think he got offended that you mentioned " you request further time for this mistake" which is obvious what made him furious, if I were in your shoes, you have to apologize.

Comment: @user41208, dont do it again and mention mistakes, I was been forced to quit from my position although doing well, because I found mistake and illustrated to my ex-PI, which made him hate me and forcing me to leave. Unfortunately, some professor get offended when their students correct them. It is supposed that the supervisor humbly learn from their mentee, but this is rare to happen, I wish he can forgive you as soon as possible.

Comment: I am also quite confused how (especially from the perspective of the UK system, in which I currently work) it was even possible _for an administrative person to grant you more time_ (once you asked), rather than your advisor. How is an admin person even aware of your schedule in such a manner, or responsible for it? I mean, it is my advisor that is expecting updates from me on a regular basis, if I went to an admin person and said "I didn't have time to implement this as my work station was broken" they would not be able to do anything with the information.

Comment: You were new, you did not realize the trouble you would be causing your P.I. Now you need to profusely apologize and eat crow. This is unfortunate because in some sense you were not made aware of the “way these things work.” In the end, that does not save you from having to give a humble and sincere apology.

Comment: Seriously?  He makes an innocent comment to the administrator that ended up embarrassing the adviser, and the adviser flies completely off the handle and begins trashing his reputation and threatening to abuse his power to cause future harm to the student's reputation and employability, and you say the *student* is the one who needs to apologize?!? That's insane!  Right now the student needs to file a massive ethics complaint about this adviser. This is blatant retaliatory behavior, and it should never be tolerated.  Seeing people take the abuser's side on here is disgusting!

Comment: @MasonWheeler: It was the opposite of an innocrent comment. It comes off as intentionally badmouthing the adviser. It's not even (or not just) about the embarrassment. Granted, the advisor has over-reacted, and been somewhat irresponsible and quite vindictive, but it's not the way you're describing it.

Comment: @MasonWheeler You have to understand that the organizational structure in academia is very flat, relative to companies. The chain of command essentially goes student, PI, department chair, school dean, president. There's no levels like "regional manager", "business sector head". It sounds to me that the OP has brought the issue up to a school-level admin, which is one step away from the "CEO" so to speak. If your lowest-level employee brought an issue about you up to such a high level in a company, you would be very upset as well.

Comment: @user71659 Perhaps I would be upset, but I would not retaliate with threats and abuse. That's a thing that should never happen, and regardless of whether or not the student was in the wrong, the teacher was *definitely* in the wrong in his response, and needs to be smacked down for it.

Comment: @MasonWheeler The only person who can possibly be fired here is the student, professors are tenured. Having actually dealt with students, that's not a bad thing. You have to understand that the vast majority of grad students have never worked a paid job, let alone a corporate job with a hierarchy and politics. The nearly all of cases I've seen are definitely originate with the student and are an issue of immaturity, and it's only been getting worse with entitlement. Personally, no sympathies from me, especially not based on a one-sided anonymous Internet story.

Comment: @user71659 Once again, **regardless of whether or not the student was in the wrong,** the teacher was definitely in the wrong in his response. It's quite possible for both sides to have made a mistake, and the teacher's behavior here is inexcusable. Please stop trying to excuse it.

Comment: @MasonWheeler Once again, **one sided Internet story**. Having seen these in person, I wouldn't trust the story even if I heard it in person. Students make things up. Entitlement and immaturity. Professors have years of experience, and in order to even half-succeed, you need to be decent at politics. I trust a professor's actions and judgement far more than a grad student. What's a normal grad student have? 4 years out of high school. That's it. In academia, you need to recognize that fact.

Comment: I can't believe people are blaming the student here. If what OP says is true, which I don't see any reason to doubt, the advisor didn't show OP a way forward at all, and OP needed more time to submit. What on earth could he have done except talk to the person responsible for deadlines if the advisor wasn't willing to do anything themselves?

Comment: @user71659 This isn't a matter of statistics, how often on average is a professor right, how often on average the student. This is a matter of one occurrence, for which we have nothing to go on except what OP told us. And there's certainly no lack of abusive professors out there, or professors who should never have got into a management situation, professors who feel out of their depth and go into fits if they think they're status is threatened...

Answer (score 1):

The damage has been made. The question is not who to blame, but how to reduce the damage.

Your best option is to do what @einpoklum suggested:

> Unless it jeopardizes the integrity of yours and others research -
>   swallow your pride/disgust, stash your ego somewhat, and apologize to
>   your advisor for your conduct. Be, or pretend to be, penitent.

I would also suggest to read the book *"How to Win Friends and Influence People"*
by Dale Carnegie. In summary, you need to ask yourself

- What do you want the other person to do?
- How can you influence them to do what you want?

Looking back:

> I have recently had some disagreement with the way my advisor handled
>   our collaboration on research. This was initially a fairly minor
>   thing. Not in the sense of what has happened, but minor in the sense
>   that I only wanted to move past it, and to continue productively, but
>   unfortunately he appeared to be too preoccupied, or for whatever
>   reason, unable or unwilling to work together on correcting our
>   results.

- You want your advisor to work with you to correct the results.
- What you did: you ignored him when he disagreed.

Does this action likely lead to the desired result? Is it a surprise that your advisor appeared not to have time to work with you?

Regardless of who to blame, whether you did was right or wrong, **your action did cause trouble to your advisor**, and you turned him into an enemy.

Having an enemy is never a good thing, in particular if you want to work in academia and they work in the same field.

- What you want your advisor to do: help with your research, or at least provide a strong reference for you to find another lab.
- How can you  achieve this?

Hint: you can't force anybody to help you, they only do it when they really want.

Note: it is your advisor's best interest to have successful students. Failing a student affects his performance and reputation too.

Comment: This is the best answer because it is the only one that addresses the question - which was not "what went wrong", but "what can I do going forward?". Don't understand why this was downvoted.